# Update a model in JS/TS using filter and other tools

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a model like so:

```
private model:Array<IMyTest> = [];
```

MyTest has a member:

```
// the testId is auto loaded from a db with a valid number while the isCorrect starts as null
testId:number;
isCorrect: boolean;
```

I have some code in another component that I want to make isCorrect toggle between true or false.

So I wrote a method like so that starts with this:

```
this.model.filter(q => q.testId === testId) ...
```

But then I want to make this.model of the one returned set isCorrect to true if it is null or false and false if it is true.

How do I chain this correctly?  It's been a while since I've had to do front end stuff.

///// EDIT of answer below with error:

```
private updateTest(testId:number): void {

    this.model = this.model.forEach(q => q.testId === testId && q.isCorrect = !q.isCorrect);
}
```

The errors I get are the first this.model being type void is not assignable to type of MyTest[] and the = !q.isCorrect has a red line under the equals.

Comment: this.model.filter(q => q.testId === testId).forEach(q => q.isCorrect = !q.isCorrect); ---Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to toggle update the `isCorrect` of the item with `testId`, here's what you are going to have.

```js
this.model = this.model.map(
  q => q.testId === testId ? { ...q,isCorrent:!q.isCorrent } : q
)
```

if you do not want to have a new object(`this.model`),then it should be

```js
this.model.forEach(
  q => q.testId === testId && (q.isCorrect = !q.isCorrect )
)
```

---

The filter will return a new object with the `testId` item, after this you have to insert it back into the `this.model` array, it will not be like this if you want to chain it

Comment: is there a bug in the = !q.isCorrent as q isn't found in my code? I am using forEach

Comment: @cdub have a check with the `this.model` array, there may be empty object.

Comment: Yeah something is wrong. My edit is above in the code.

Comment: the = ! says ',' expected still. not sure why

Comment: @cdub updated and tested, the `(q.isCorrent = !q.isCorrent)` shoud be wrapped. sorry for the mistake.

Comment: will this work if all q.isCorrent starts as null or undefined. Just checking stuff out.